# Changing value of var when clicking button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been trying to figure out how to change the value of a var when clicking different buttons. I should be able to change between "Green" and "Yellow" to then set that background color when an element of the table is clicked.
I dont know why when i click the GREEN button it works but not on the other one.
Thank you very much in advance!

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<meta name="language" content="english">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
<title>Table Highlighting</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 
$(function(){   
 
 var color = 'blue';
 

$('button').click(function (){
    color='#33FF36';
});
 
$('button2').click(function (){
    color='#F0FF00';
});
 

  $('td').toggle( function() {
    $(this).css('background', color);
  },function(){
  $(this).css('background', 'white');
  });
} );
</script>
<style>
table
{
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
td
{
 padding: 5px;
 border: 1px solid #666666;
 cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table width="160">
 <tr>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">11</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">12</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">13</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">14</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">21</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">22</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">
  23</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">24</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">31</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">32</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">33</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">34</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">41</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">42</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">43</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">44</td>
 </tr>
</table>
<button id="button" >Green</button>
 <button id="button2" >Yellow</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not using an `id` selector on the buttons, they need changing from:

```
$('button').click(function (){
    color='#33FF36';
});

$('button2').click(function (){
    color='#F0FF00';
});
```

to:

```
$('#button').click(function (){
    color='#33FF36';
});

$('#button2').click(function (){
    color='#F0FF00';
});
```

Here's a working example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<meta name="language" content="english">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
<title>Table Highlighting</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 
$(function(){   
 
 var color = 'blue';
 

$('#button').click(function (){
    color='#33FF36';
});
 
$('#button2').click(function (){
    color='#F0FF00';
});
 

  $('td').toggle( function() {
    $(this).css('background', color);
  },function(){
  $(this).css('background', 'white');
  });
} );
</script>
<style>
table
{
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
td
{
 padding: 5px;
 border: 1px solid #666666;
 cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table width="160">
 <tr>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">11</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">12</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">13</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">14</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">21</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">22</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">
  23</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">24</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">31</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">32</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">33</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">34</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">41</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">42</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">43</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">44</td>
 </tr>
</table>
<button id="button" >Green</button>
 <button id="button2" >Yellow</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Great SWC! Thank you vert much for your help! Appreciate it a lot. Already apply the changes and works! I would like to know something else. Is it possible to save somehow this settings? I mean, the combination of colors that each person creates. The idea is to create a username and password so each person can create its own color code. It will be used for some math charts.

Comment: It would be possible. The best approach might be to create an array from the grid and then that could be saved. So for row one you might have something like `[0,1,2,1]` with the numbers corresponding to the different color options. That's just one way of approaching it though.

Answer (score 0):

Your selectors are wrong, if you want to select with id, use #id:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
  <meta name="language" content="english">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
  <title>Table Highlighting</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      var color = 'blue';

      $('#button').click(function() {
        color = '#33FF36';
      });

      $('#button2').click(function() {
        color = '#F0FF00';
      });

      $('td').toggle(function() {
        $(this).css('background', color);
      }, function() {
        $(this).css('background', 'white');
      });
    });
  </script>
  <style>
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    
    td {
      padding: 5px;
      border: 1px solid #666666;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table width="160">
    <tr>
      <td width="40" height="40" align="center">11</td>
      <td width="40" height="40" align="center">12</td>
      <td width="40" height="40" align="center">13</td>
      <td width="40" height="40" align="center">14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="40" height="40" align="center">21</td>
      <td width="40" height="40" align="center">22</td>
      <td width="40" height="40" align="center">
        23</td>
      <td width="40" height="40" align="center">24</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="40" height="40" align="center">31</td>
      <td width="40" height="40" align="center">32</td>
      <td width="40" height="40" align="center">33</td>
      <td width="40" height="40" align="center">34</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="40" height="40" align="center">41</td>
      <td width="40" height="40" align="center">42</td>
      <td width="40" height="40" align="center">43</td>
      <td width="40" height="40" align="center">44</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button id="button">Green</button>
  <button id="button2">Yellow</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much to everyone who helped me so far! I would like to know something else: Is it possible to save somehow this settings? I mean, the combination of colors that each person creates. The idea is to create a username and password so each person can create its own color code. It will be used for some math charts.

Answer (score 0):

There were a few things wrong with your code, like no # in your id identifiers. I'm not too sure what you were trying to achieve with your toggle, but try the code out below and see if it's what you were looking for:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
  <meta name="language" content="english">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
  <title>Table Highlighting</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var color = 'blue';

    $(function() {

      $('#button').on("click", function() {
        color = '#33FF36';
        changeBg();
      });

      $('#button2').on("click", function() {
        color = '#F0FF00';
        changeBg();
      });

    });

    function changeBg() {
      $('td').css('background', color);
    }
  </script>
  <style>
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    
    td {
      padding: 5px;
      border: 1px solid #666666;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table width="160">
    <tr>
      <td width="40" height="40" align="center">11</td>
      <td width="40" height="40" align="center">12</td>
      <td width="40" height="40" align="center">13</td>
      <td width="40" height="40" align="center">14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="40" height="40" align="center">21</td>
      <td width="40" height="40" align="center">22</td>
      <td width="40" height="40" align="center">
        23</td>
      <td width="40" height="40" align="center">24</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="40" height="40" align="center">31</td>
      <td width="40" height="40" align="center">32</td>
      <td width="40" height="40" align="center">33</td>
      <td width="40" height="40" align="center">34</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="40" height="40" align="center">41</td>
      <td width="40" height="40" align="center">42</td>
      <td width="40" height="40" align="center">43</td>
      <td width="40" height="40" align="center">44</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button id="button">Green</button>
  <button id="button2">Yellow</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer MichaelvE but is not what i was looking for. Actually what im trying to do are some math charts that each person who access (via user and pass) can be able to save their own patterns. I just put this table as a random example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use from this code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<meta name="language" content="english">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
<title>Table Highlighting</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 
$(function(){   
 
 var bgcolor = 'blue';
 

$('button').click(function (){

   var x = document.getElementsByTagName('td'); 
   x[0].style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";

});
 
$('button2').click(function (){
 
  var y = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
  y[1].style.backgroundColor = "#FF0040";
});
 

  $('td').toggle( function() {
    $(this).css('background', bgcolor);
  }
  
  ,
  function(){
  $(this).css('background', 'white');
  });
} );
</script>


<style>
table
{
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
td
{
 padding: 5px;
 border: 1px solid #666666;
 cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table width="160">
 <tr>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">11</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">12</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">13</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">14</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">21</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">22</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">
  23</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">24</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">31</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">32</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">33</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">34</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">41</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">42</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">43</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">44</td>
 </tr>
</table>
<button id="button" >Green</button>
 <button id="button2" >Yellow</button>
</body>
</html>
```